# How to add enumerate or a simple counter inside a message box

Tags: python

I developped a small application, but I would like to know how to add a simple counter inside a message box.

The message box, from QT designer, can appear 3 times. I would like to see the number in the message box.

Let's say it appears the first time, I should see -> 1, a second time, I should see -> 2, a third time -> 3.

Here is the part of the code:

```
            else:
                second_message_box(QMessageBox.Critical,
                                   "Attention!",
                                   "Il n'est pas possible d'ajouter L'inspecteur " + employeesChosen[i],
                                   QMessageBox.Ok)
```

I tried this, but it always gives me "1", it never iterate, even when the message box opens more than one time.

```
else:
    count = 0
    count += 1
    second_message_box(QMessageBox.Critical,
                       str(count),
                       "Il n'est pas possible d'ajouter L'inspecteur " + employeesChosen[i],
                       QMessageBox.Ok)
```

edit 3:

I did that

```
count = 0

def foo():
   ...

   else:
    global counter
    count += 1
    second_message_box(QMessageBox.Critical,
                       str(count),
                       "Il n'est pas possible d'ajouter L'inspecteur " + employeesChosen[i],
                       QMessageBox.Ok)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create a variable named `count` and modify that every time that `else` statement is called.

Here's an example:

```
def foo():
    count = 0

    for i in range(5):
       count += 1
```

The `+=` operator increments the variable by the count of the integer on the right. If you happen to place the variable outside any function `def` blocks, be sure to indicate that the global variable of `count` needs to be modified.

```
count = 0

def foo():
   
   for i in range(5):
        global count
        count += 1
```

You can just `print` it after a certain line if you need to see it in the console.

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer. Can you please take a look at my question? I edited it.

Comment: Is the `count` variable inside a function? It might be reassigning the variable with an int of zero. If it is, follow the second code block I wrote to have it persist through the entire execution.

Comment: yes it is inside a function, i will try your way right now

Comment: it worked! Thank you good sir. One last question, is the Global variable safe to use? Will this break something in my code? IM new sorry. Please check Edit 3 in my OP

Comment: Unless you already have a variable called `count` somewhere in the global scope, you should be fine. If it does break, it should be a simple fix as there's only so many places to look.